# missing num_members attribute for conversation.info slack API call

Tags: slack-api

I'm trying to get the number of members in a Slack conversation (channel, group, etc.) following the documentation available at: https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.info. However, the attribute `num_members` is not returned in the response. Below, I add an example of what the API returns for a public channel.

Am I doing something wrong or the documentation is just not up-to-date?

```
{
    "channel": {
    "created": 1487814389,
    "creator": "XXXXX",
    "id": "XXXXXX",
    "is_archived": false,
    "is_channel": true,
    "is_ext_shared": false,
    "is_general": false,
    "is_group": false,
    "is_im": false,
    "is_member": true,
    "is_mpim": false,
    "is_org_shared": false,
    "is_pending_ext_shared": false,
    "is_private": false,
    "is_shared": false,
    "last_read": "1508258940.000289",
    "name": "clients",
    "name_normalized": "clients",
    "pending_shared": [],
    "previous_names": [],
    "purpose": {
        "creator": "XXXXXX",
        "last_set": 1487814389,
        "value": "Talk about the XXXX"
    },
    "shared_team_ids": [
        "XXXXX"
    ],
    "topic": {
        "creator": "",
        "last_set": 0,
        "value": ""
    },
    "unlinked": 0
}
```

Comment: Can you please add what kind of conversation this is? From the result I am guessing its a public channel?

Comment: I am getting the same result for public channels though. So its looks like that is how the Slack API currently behaves. You may want to send a request to the Slack team to clarify maybe? Also, you can still use `conversations.members` to get the number of members.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken thank you for the prompt answer! I have modified my question to include that I'm querying a public channel

Comment: I have just received a reply from Slack support, they say that the attribute `num_members` is not included in conversations.info, they will correct the documentation. They also suggest to use `conversations.members` (https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.members).

Comment: nice! this will be great help for others who might stumble over the same issue. are making this into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Slack support says that the documentation is not correct (the attribute `num_members` is not included in the `conversations.info` response).

The number of members can be obtained using `conversations.members` API call and pagination. An example in Python is available at: 
https://github.com/chaoss/grimoirelab-perceval/blob/master/perceval/backends/core/slack.py#L318